# BehaviorSubject partial change does not trigger subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working with Typescript 3.4.5 and Angular 8.

Consider the following interface:

```js
// This is an interface which represents a piece of data, which will be partially updated
export interface TextBrick {
  kind: 'text';
  content: string;
}

export class TestService {
  test$ = new BehaviorSubject<TextBrick>({kind: 'text', content: 'initial'});

  get test(): TextBrick {
    return this.test$.value;
  }

  set test(v: TextBrick) {
    console.log('set', v);
    this.test$.next(v);
  }
}
```

The idea is to subscribe to the `test$` BehaviorSubject to watch the `test.content` change.

Consider now the following test:

```js
test('test', () => {
  const instance = new TestService();

  // Watch subscription
  instance.test$.subscribe((v) => console.log('sub', v));

  // 1) Full replace, subscription triggered
  instance.test = {kind: 'text', content: 'fullreplace'};

  // 2) Partial replace, subscription not triggered
  instance.test.content = 'aa';

  // But the value of the BehaviorSubject was updated! WTF?!
  console.log('end', instance.test); 
});
```

The console output is the following:

```
sub { kind: 'text', content: 'intitial' }    // Expected behavior
set { kind: 'text', content: 'fullreplace' } // Expected behavior
sub { kind: 'text', content: 'fullreplace' } // Expected behavior
end { kind: 'text', content: 'aa' }          // Sounds really weird!
```

There is obviously a problem with "partial setter" (I don't know how to name that), when I set the `instance.test.content`. I carefully read the [Typescript documentation on setters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors), but this use case is not mentioned.

My first hypothesis was that the `set test()` was not called, which make sense because when I add a console.log in the setter, I don't see the "partial" set of `'aa'`. But how can be the value of the behavior subject updated without triggering my subscription callback?

Any help or ressource will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
instance.test = {kind: 'text', content: 'fullreplace'};
```

This line calls the setter function

```
instance.test.content = 'aa';
```

This line calls the getter function and then mutates the contents of the behavior subject, you should not mutate the contents of the behavior subject.

Get the value and then update the value with a new object, we don't mutate objects in the world of reactive programming.

```
const value = instance.test;

instance.test = { ...value, content: 'aa' };
```

Comment: True, I just checked. Sadly, I thought that it would have been possible to update the BaheviorSubject to `instance.text.content`. Thank you very mouch for your quick answer!

Comment: Have a read of my article on Angular state management, it might get you thinking about it https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb